# Pyqt5 QgraphicsView pan past scroll bar limits

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicsview

I have a set of predetermined X and Y coordinates that I am using to place `QGraphicsItem`'s as points and then placing each of those points in a `QGraphicsView`. I have my panning button set to be the middle mouse button, but I can only pan if I have zoomed in. Also, I can only pan to my furthers point.

Is there a way to set the `QGraphicsView` so that it will not stop panning at a point and that I can pan at any zoom level? Also as a side note, Later I would like to be able to select these points to set and get attributes from them, so I would still like to ability to interact with them?

**Update**

I made a couple of gif's to show how the controls currently work and then how I would like them to work.

**Currently**

You can see here I am not able to move past the limits of the scroll bars
[image]

**What I would like**

I would like to be able to move the screen past where the squares are being placed so that if the user desires they can move some off the screen or they could zoom out further than where `fitInView` would allow. I know the zoom part is in my wheel event and just haven't changed it yet. The big thing is being able to move them past at any zoom level.

[image]

please let me know if you need more explanation.

**Code**

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys
from math import sqrt

class Point(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super(Point, self).__init__()
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
        self.rectF = QRectF(0, 0, 30, 30)
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self._brush = QBrush(Qt.black)

    def setBrush(self, brush):
        self._brush = brush
        self.update()

    def boundingRect(self):
        return self.rectF

    def paint(self, painter=None, style=None, widget=None):
        painter.fillRect(self.rectF, self._brush)

    def hoverMoveEvent(self, event):
        point = event.pos().toPoint()
        print(point)
        QGraphicsItem.hoverMoveEvent(self, event)


class Viewer(QGraphicsView):
    photoClicked = pyqtSignal(QPoint)
    rectChanged = pyqtSignal(QRect)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Viewer, self).__init__(parent)
        self.rubberBand = QRubberBand(QRubberBand.Rectangle, self)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.origin = QPoint()
        self.changeRubberBand = False

        self._zoom = 0
        self._empty = True
        self._scene = QGraphicsScene(self)

        self.setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setResizeAnchor(QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.area = float()
        self.setPoints()
        QTimer.singleShot(0, self.fitInView) # This is done so that it can fit into view on load

    def setItems(self):
            self.data = {'x': [-2414943.8686, -2417160.6592, -2417160.6592, -2417856.1783, -2417054.7618, -2416009.9966, -2416012.5232, -2418160.8952, -2418160.8952, -2416012.5232, -2417094.7694, -2417094.7694], 'y': [10454269.7008,
     10454147.2672, 10454147.2672, 10453285.2456, 10452556.8132, 10453240.2808, 10455255.8752, 10455183.1912, 10455183.1912, 10455255.8752, 10456212.5959, 10456212.5959]}
            maxX = max(self.data['x'])
            minX = min(self.data['x'])
            maxY = max(self.data['y'])
            minY = min(self.data['y'])
            distance = sqrt((maxX-minX)**2+(maxY-minY)**2)

            self.area = QRectF(minX, minY, distance, distance)
            for i,x in enumerate(self.data['x']):
                x = self.data['x'][i]
                y = self.data['y'][i]
                p = Point(x,y)
                p.setPos(x,y)
                self._scene.addItem(p)
            self.setScene(self._scene)



    def fitInView(self, scale=True):
        rect = QRectF(self.area)
        if not rect.isNull():
            self.setSceneRect(rect)

            unity = self.transform().mapRect(QRectF(0, 0, 1, 1))
            self.scale(1 / unity.width(), 1 / unity.height())
            viewrect = self.viewport().rect()
            scenerect = self.transform().mapRect(rect)
            factor = min(viewrect.width() / scenerect.width(),
                             viewrect.height() / scenerect.height())
            self.scale(factor, factor)
            self._zoom = 0


    def setPoints(self):
        self._zoom = 0
        self.setItems()
        self.setDragMode(self.ScrollHandDrag)
        # self.fitInView()

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
            if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
                factor = 1.25
                self._zoom += 1
            else:
                factor = 0.8
                self._zoom -= 1
            if self._zoom > 0:
                self.scale(factor, factor)
            elif self._zoom == 0:
                self.fitInView()
            else:
                self._zoom = 0


    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:

            self.origin = event.pos()
            self.rubberBand.setGeometry(QRect(self.origin, QSize()))
            self.rectChanged.emit(self.rubberBand.geometry())
            self.rubberBand.show()
            self.changeRubberBand = True
            return
            #QGraphicsView.mousePressEvent(self,event)
        elif event.button() == Qt.MidButton:
            self.viewport().setCursor(Qt.ClosedHandCursor)
            self.original_event = event
            handmade_event = QMouseEvent(QEvent.MouseButtonPress,QPointF(event.pos()),Qt.LeftButton,event.buttons(),Qt.KeyboardModifiers())
            QGraphicsView.mousePressEvent(self,handmade_event)

        super(Viewer, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.changeRubberBand = False
            QGraphicsView.mouseReleaseEvent(self,event)
        elif event.button() == Qt.MidButton:
            self.viewport().setCursor(Qt.OpenHandCursor)
            handmade_event = QMouseEvent(QEvent.MouseButtonRelease,QPointF(event.pos()),Qt.LeftButton,event.buttons(),Qt.KeyboardModifiers())
            QGraphicsView.mouseReleaseEvent(self,handmade_event)
        super(Viewer, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)


    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.changeRubberBand:
            self.rubberBand.setGeometry(QRect(self.origin, event.pos()).normalized())
            self.rectChanged.emit(self.rubberBand.geometry())
            QGraphicsView.mouseMoveEvent(self,event)
        super(Viewer, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.viewer = Viewer(self)
        self.btnLoad = QToolButton(self)
        self.btnLoad.setText('Fit Into View')
        self.btnLoad.clicked.connect(self.fitPoints)

        VBlayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        VBlayout.addWidget(self.viewer)
        HBlayout = QHBoxLayout()
        HBlayout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
        HBlayout.addWidget(self.btnLoad)

        VBlayout.addLayout(HBlayout)
        self.viewer.fitInView()

    def fitPoints(self):
        self.viewer.fitInView()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 800, 600)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I updated , please give it a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update2**

Please try this Code. Is this appropriate answer for you?
If so, I want to add new explanation.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys
from math import sqrt
class Line(QGraphicsLineItem):
    def __init__(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        super(Line, self).__init__()
        pen = self.pen()
        pen.setWidth(10)
        pen.setColor(Qt.gray)
        pen.setStyle(Qt.SolidLine)

        self.setPen(pen)
        self.origin = self.pos()
        self.setZValue(1)
        self.setLine(QLineF(x1, y1, x2, y2))
class Point(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super(Point, self).__init__()
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
        self.rectF = QRectF(0, 0, 30, 30)
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.origin = QPointF(self.pos())
        self._brush = QBrush(Qt.black)
        self.setZValue(2)
    def setBrush(self, brush):
        self._brush = brush
        self.update()

    def boundingRect(self):
        return self.rectF

    def paint(self, painter=None, style=None, widget=None):
        painter.fillRect(self.rectF, self._brush)

    def hoverMoveEvent(self, event):
        point = event.pos().toPoint()
        print(point)
        QGraphicsItem.hoverMoveEvent(self, event)


class Viewer(QGraphicsView):
    photoClicked = pyqtSignal(QPoint)
    rectChanged = pyqtSignal(QRect)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Viewer, self).__init__(parent)
        self.rubberBand = QRubberBand(QRubberBand.Rectangle, self)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.origin = QPoint()
        self.changeRubberBand = False
        self.mid_panning = False     



        self._zoom = 0
        self._empty = True
        self._scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        self._scene.setBackgroundBrush(Qt.white)
        self.white_board = QGraphicsRectItem()
        self.white_board.setZValue(1)
        self.white_board.setBrush(Qt.white)
        self.setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setResizeAnchor(QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.area = float()
        self.setPoints()
        self._old_x = QCursor.pos().x()
        self._old_y = QCursor.pos().y()

        QTimer.singleShot(0, self.fitInView) # This is done so that it can fit into view on load

    def setItems(self):
            self.data = {'x': [-2414943.8686, -2417160.6592, -2417160.6592, -2417856.1783, -2417054.7618, -2416009.9966, -2416012.5232, -2418160.8952, -2418160.8952, -2416012.5232, -2417094.7694, -2417094.7694], 'y': [10454269.7008,
     10454147.2672, 10454147.2672, 10453285.2456, 10452556.8132, 10453240.2808, 10455255.8752, 10455183.1912, 10455183.1912, 10455255.8752, 10456212.5959, 10456212.5959]}
            maxX = max(self.data['x'])
            minX = min(self.data['x'])
            maxY = max(self.data['y'])
            minY = min(self.data['y'])
            distance = sqrt((maxX-minX)**2+(maxY-minY)**2)

            self.area = QRectF(minX , minY , distance , distance )
            self.white_board.setRect(QRectF(minX , minY , distance , distance ))
            self._scene.addItem(self.white_board)
            line1 = Line(minX, minY, minX+distance, minY+distance)
            line2 = Line(minX+distance, minY, minX, minY+distance)
            self._scene.addItem(line1)
            self._scene.addItem(line2)
            for i,x in enumerate(self.data['x']):
                x = self.data['x'][i]
                y = self.data['y'][i]
                p = Point(x,y)
                p.setPos(x,y)
                self._scene.addItem(p)

            self.setScene(self._scene)


    def make_area2(self, area):
        x = area.x()
        y = area.y()
        width = area.width()
        height = area.height()
        x -= 2*x
        y -= 2*y
        width = width*2
        height = height*2
        area = QRectF(x, y, width, height)
        return area
    def fitInView(self, scale=True):
        rect = QRectF(self.area)
        if not rect.isNull():
            self.setSceneRect(rect)
            unity = self.transform().mapRect(QRectF(0, 0, 1, 1))
            print(unity.width(), unity.height())
            self.scale(1 / unity.width(), 1 / unity.height())
            viewrect = self.viewport().rect()
            scenerect = self.transform().mapRect(rect)
            factor = min(viewrect.width() / scenerect.width(),
                             viewrect.height() / scenerect.height())
            print(scenerect.width(), scenerect.height())
            self.scale(factor, factor)

            self._zoom = 0



    def setPoints(self):
        self._zoom = 0
        self.setItems()
        self.setDragMode(self.ScrollHandDrag)
        # self.fitInView()

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
            if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
                factor = 1.25
                self._zoom += 1
            else:
                factor = 0.8
                self._zoom -= 1
            if self._zoom > 0:
                self.scale(factor, factor)
            elif self._zoom == 0:
                self.fitInView()
            else:
                self._zoom = 0


    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:

            self.origin = event.pos()
            self.rubberBand.setGeometry(QRect(self.origin, QSize()))
            self.rectChanged.emit(self.rubberBand.geometry())
            self.rubberBand.show()
            self.changeRubberBand = True
            return
            #QGraphicsView.mousePressEvent(self,event)
        elif event.button() == Qt.MidButton:
            self.viewport().setCursor(Qt.ClosedHandCursor)
            self.origin = event.pos()
            self.original_event = event
            self.mid_panning = True
            self.scene_origin = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
            self._old_x = QCursor.pos().x()
            self._old_y = QCursor.pos().y()
            for i in self._scene.items():

                i.origin = i.pos()
            # I recommend that you get the all item position.
            handmade_event = QMouseEvent(QEvent.MouseButtonPress,QPointF(event.pos()),Qt.LeftButton,event.buttons(),Qt.KeyboardModifiers())
            QGraphicsView.mousePressEvent(self,handmade_event)

        super(Viewer, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.changeRubberBand = False
            QGraphicsView.mouseReleaseEvent(self,event)
        elif event.button() == Qt.MidButton:
            self.viewport().setCursor(Qt.OpenHandCursor)
            handmade_event = QMouseEvent(QEvent.MouseButtonRelease,QPointF(event.pos()),Qt.LeftButton,event.buttons(),Qt.KeyboardModifiers())
            self.mid_panning = False
            # here you set the original point.
            for i in self._scene.items():
                i.setPos(i.origin)
            QGraphicsView.mouseReleaseEvent(self,handmade_event)
        super(Viewer, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)
    def calc_offset(self, x, y):
        offset_x = x - int(self.viewport().width()/2)
        offset_y = y - int(self.viewport().height()/2)
        return offset_x, offset_y

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):        
        if self.changeRubberBand:
            self.rubberBand.setGeometry(QRect(self.origin, event.pos()).normalized())
            self.rectChanged.emit(self.rubberBand.geometry())
            QGraphicsView.mouseMoveEvent(self,event)
        elif self.mid_panning:         

            new_x = event.x()
            new_y = event.y()
            offset_x, offset_y = self.calc_offset(new_x, new_y)
            for item in self._scene.items():
                item.setPos(QPointF(item.pos().x() - (new_x - self._old_x)*10, item.pos().y() - (new_y - self._old_y)*10))     


            self._old_x = new_x
            self._old_y = new_y
            return

        super(Viewer, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.viewer = Viewer(self)
        self.btnLoad = QToolButton(self)
        self.btnLoad.setText('Fit Into View')
        self.btnLoad.clicked.connect(self.fitPoints)

        VBlayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        VBlayout.addWidget(self.viewer)
        HBlayout = QHBoxLayout()
        HBlayout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
        HBlayout.addWidget(self.btnLoad)

        VBlayout.addLayout(HBlayout)
        self.viewer.fitInView()

    def fitPoints(self):
        self.viewer.fitInView()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(300, 400, 800, 600)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Update**

The key solution is to use `scroll(dx, dy)`.

**Explanation**

At the first time, I doubted if there was the place of "offscreen" or not.
The reason is `QGraphicsView` only shows `QGraphicsScene` and `QGraphicsItem` on the scene.`QGraphicsView` can show all the scene or the part of the scene,I thought it cannot show the "offscreen".

I have experienced `pygame`,so I attempted to implement the idea of "offset",but `pygame` has originally an infinite vast of screen and only shows the slight part of it.So We can see the "offscreen".On the contrast,`QGraphicsScene` is a finite screen the user decide the range by `setSceneRect`.And `fitInView` means the same range of screen.

But `QGraphicsView` is a widget for showing the scene.We can scroll the widget.
So, We can do the same thing by scrolling the widget itself.

**code.**

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys
from math import sqrt

class Point(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super(Point, self).__init__()
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
        self.rectF = QRectF(0, 0, 30, 30)
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self._brush = QBrush(Qt.black)

    def setBrush(self, brush):
        self._brush = brush
        self.update()

    def boundingRect(self):
        return self.rectF

    def paint(self, painter=None, style=None, widget=None):
        painter.fillRect(self.rectF, self._brush)

    def hoverMoveEvent(self, event):
        point = event.pos().toPoint()
        print(point)
        QGraphicsItem.hoverMoveEvent(self, event)


class Viewer(QGraphicsView):
    photoClicked = pyqtSignal(QPoint)
    rectChanged = pyqtSignal(QRect)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Viewer, self).__init__(parent)
        self.rubberBand = QRubberBand(QRubberBand.Rectangle, self)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.origin = QPoint()
        self.changeRubberBand = False
        self.mid_panning = False     



        self._zoom = 0
        self._empty = True
        self._scene = QGraphicsScene(self)

        self.setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setResizeAnchor(QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.area = float()
        self.setPoints()
        QTimer.singleShot(0, self.fitInView) # This is done so that it can fit into view on load

    def setItems(self):
            self.data = {'x': [-2414943.8686, -2417160.6592, -2417160.6592, -2417856.1783, -2417054.7618, -2416009.9966, -2416012.5232, -2418160.8952, -2418160.8952, -2416012.5232, -2417094.7694, -2417094.7694], 'y': [10454269.7008,
     10454147.2672, 10454147.2672, 10453285.2456, 10452556.8132, 10453240.2808, 10455255.8752, 10455183.1912, 10455183.1912, 10455255.8752, 10456212.5959, 10456212.5959]}
            maxX = max(self.data['x'])
            minX = min(self.data['x'])
            maxY = max(self.data['y'])
            minY = min(self.data['y'])
            distance = sqrt((maxX-minX)**2+(maxY-minY)**2)

            self.area = QRectF(minX, minY, distance, distance)
            for i,x in enumerate(self.data['x']):
                x = self.data['x'][i]
                y = self.data['y'][i]
                p = Point(x,y)
                p.setPos(x,y)
                self._scene.addItem(p)
            self.setScene(self._scene)



    def fitInView(self, scale=True):
        rect = QRectF(self.area)
        if not rect.isNull():
            self.setSceneRect(rect)
            unity = self.transform().mapRect(QRectF(0, 0, 1, 1))
            print(unity.width(), unity.height())
            self.scale(1 / unity.width(), 1 / unity.height())
            viewrect = self.viewport().rect()
            scenerect = self.transform().mapRect(rect)
            factor = min(viewrect.width() / scenerect.width(),
                             viewrect.height() / scenerect.height())
            self.scale(factor, factor)
            self._zoom = 0


    def setPoints(self):
        self._zoom = 0
        self.setItems()
        self.setDragMode(self.ScrollHandDrag)
        # self.fitInView()

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
            if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
                factor = 1.25
                self._zoom += 1
            else:
                factor = 0.8
                self._zoom -= 1
            if self._zoom > 0:
                self.scale(factor, factor)
            elif self._zoom == 0:
                self.fitInView()
            else:
                self._zoom = 0


    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:

            self.origin = event.pos()
            self.rubberBand.setGeometry(QRect(self.origin, QSize()))
            self.rectChanged.emit(self.rubberBand.geometry())
            self.rubberBand.show()
            self.changeRubberBand = True
            return
            #QGraphicsView.mousePressEvent(self,event)
        elif event.button() == Qt.MidButton:
            self.viewport().setCursor(Qt.ClosedHandCursor)
            self.origin = event.pos()
            self.original_event = event
            self.mid_panning = True
            self.scene_origin = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
            handmade_event = QMouseEvent(QEvent.MouseButtonPress,QPointF(event.pos()),Qt.LeftButton,event.buttons(),Qt.KeyboardModifiers())
            QGraphicsView.mousePressEvent(self,handmade_event)

        super(Viewer, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.changeRubberBand = False
            QGraphicsView.mouseReleaseEvent(self,event)
        elif event.button() == Qt.MidButton:
            self.viewport().setCursor(Qt.OpenHandCursor)
            handmade_event = QMouseEvent(QEvent.MouseButtonRelease,QPointF(event.pos()),Qt.LeftButton,event.buttons(),Qt.KeyboardModifiers())
            self.mid_panning = False
            QGraphicsView.mouseReleaseEvent(self,handmade_event)
        super(Viewer, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)
    def calc_offset(self, x, y):
        offset_x = x - int(self.viewport().width()/2)
        offset_y = y - int(self.viewport().height()/2)
        return offset_x, offset_y
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):        
        if self.changeRubberBand:
            self.rubberBand.setGeometry(QRect(self.origin, event.pos()).normalized())
            self.rectChanged.emit(self.rubberBand.geometry())
            QGraphicsView.mouseMoveEvent(self,event)
        elif self.mid_panning:         
            offset_x, offset_y = self.calc_offset(event.pos().x(), event.pos().y())
            self.scroll(offset_x,offset_y)
            return

        super(Viewer, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.viewer = Viewer(self)
        self.btnLoad = QToolButton(self)
        self.btnLoad.setText('Fit Into View')
        self.btnLoad.clicked.connect(self.fitPoints)

        VBlayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        VBlayout.addWidget(self.viewer)
        HBlayout = QHBoxLayout()
        HBlayout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
        HBlayout.addWidget(self.btnLoad)

        VBlayout.addLayout(HBlayout)
        self.viewer.fitInView()

    def fitPoints(self):
        self.viewer.fitInView()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(300, 400, 800, 600)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but what I would like to achieve is the user to be able to pan past the bounds that are placed, at any zoom level. So if the user wants to pan even at the maximum zoom level and move all of the objects off-screen in any direction, they can. The controls feel funny to me that has stopping points for the users pan. I hope I am explaining this correctly.

Comment: I have updated my original post to hopefully make it more clear on what I am trying to achieve. Thank you for your help

Comment: @laxer I see, I understand it.Thank you for your update.

Comment: That is great! I will have to play with it a little to get the zoom correct because of my own wheel event, that will get me on the right track. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Guys, I have quite same question , but I don't want to move QGraphicsView itself, I want to navigate inside QGraphicsScene. Basically being able to translate unlimited inside scene itself. Do you know how to do that ?

Comment: @Vlad I understand what you are saying.At this moment, I don't know the solution.But give us some time for thinking it, I endevour to solve it at least.You have deleted your previous question, but you may be good to put the question again.

Comment: I see, thank you a lot. It's just recently I was making too many duplicates about PyQt and after I saw your answer it looked like perfect solution to my problem  :)

Comment: @Vlad *please* give us, I'm sorry.And I have looked over your previous code, parhaps it may be here in the past answer before editting.I think you want to do the same action in this question, currently part.But I think you may as well put the question because it may be a new question in actual.

Comment: If we can change the code so you can pan around the scene and not the view that would benefit me as well.

Comment: @laxer Yes, I have already an idea.But I don't make sure if the idea is executable in actual code.

Comment: I think it is almost there. When I run the code if I release the middle button all of the points always return to center. Would it be possible to have all the dots stay where the user releases them? Also, It appears everything is panning in the opposite direction than what seems to be natural. for example, if I zoom in and try and grab a dot and move it to the right, the dot moves to the left. It is like that in all directions.

Comment: @laxer You don't want the points to go home?If you release them, let the points stay there?

Comment: No, I would like the user to be able to choose the position even if that means they are off the screen, in my actual program I will have a button for the user to recenter them if they choose too.

Comment: @laxer hmm,I think you put your sample program for this question, but you use actually your own program for users.you use alternative program for it,I don't say you put the true program, ok, I understand what you are saying.anyway, my new code is almost to your purpose.So,is it your new question?Is it the new manipulation to my code?

Comment: Or it is in the range of "this" question?

Comment: In fact, I must imagine your own program,your saying buttons are not here,at least, So, I'm a little at a loss If I should write my code here.

Comment: Yes the program is actually quite large and most of what is apart of the program does not relate to the question. I basically would just like the user to be able to drag the points anywhere they choose within the view.

Comment: @laxer thanks to reply, please make a new question for it if you want to go forward through SOF.I think it is not the emergency.If you like it.Probably, other users out of me answer for it at the higher possibility.

Comment: Thank you for your help with this problem, I appreciate it.